# A movie where a supernatural girl gets hit by a car and then wakes up to chase another girl

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recently saw a 30 second clip of an unidentified movie. I've been searching ever since to find it again and try to see the movie.  The clip starts with a girl laying on the street, apparently hit by a driver in a truck. Another girl standing by steals the truck in a hurry. The girl who was hit then wakes up, much to the surprise of the original driver. The girl than runs super fast after the stolen truck. The scene ends when the supernatural girl jumps into the truck, scaring the other.

Anyone know what movie or TV show this could be from?

**Edit**
More details: This was a live action movie and everyone in the scene was Caucasian. The guy who hit the girl was older but don't recall how old and he was driving a pick up truck, and this happened out in the country.

Unfortunately, it wasn't the Terminator scene suggested in the comments; I checked.

Comment: Live action film? Were the girls Caucasian? Black? Indian? Asian? Was it set in a city? The countryside? A planetary colony? Do you remember anyone's hair color?

Comment: Maybe "Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines"? I Think I remember a scene where the female terminator is hit by a truck, and the good guys steal it and then the terminator gets up and chases it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are talking about [Tomorrowland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrowland_(film)); see if this looks familiar:

(about 50 seconds in, if it doesn't start where I tagged it.)

The terrified lady is Cassey; the main character.  The girl who driving, then hit when she exits the car is Athena; she has a bit in common with a terminator, if much friendlier :)

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!